# New 2020 GNAT Ada installation failing to build an old 2015 project

Tags: ada, gnat

I recently installed GNAT Ada (2020) and GNAVI GWindows on a new PC.
On trying to build an old project developed under the 2015 version, I get this:

*No candidate interpretations match the actuals:
Too many arguments in call to "Put"
expected private type "Printer_Canvas_Type" defined at gwindows-drawing.ads:603
found private type "Canvas_Type" defined at gwindows-drawing.ads:96*

This is one of the several similar pieces of code that produce the same result (MapCanvas is declared elsewhere as Canvas_Type):

```
     Put (MapCanvas, (DATUM_BASE_X +
                     (x * 10 * GRID_MONAD_SPACING)) +
                          (5 * GRID_MONAD_SPACING),
                      y - (GRID_MONAD_SPACING + 5),
                      Integer'Image (x));
```

Possibly related, I also get this in regard to the last argument in the call to Put - Integer'Image(x)

*expected type "Standard.Wide_String"
found type"Standard.String"*

As an experiment, I tried converting the last argument using To_Wide_String (Integer'Image (x)) but the result was the same.

Elsewhere, similar code with a literal compiles ok:

```
     Put (MapCanvas, (DATUM_BASE_X - 1 +
                     (GRID_MONAD_SPACING / 2) +
                     (x * 10 * GRID_MONAD_SPACING)),
                      y + 20 + (60 * GRID_MONAD_SPACING),
                     "0        2        4        6        8       ");
```

On the previous PC with GNAT Ada 2015, everything compiled. I've compared the declarations
of Put in gwindows-drawing.ads in the old and new installations of GWindows and they are identical.
Unfortunately I can no longer build on the old PC without a lot of backtracking - the old project drive
is in use elsewhere, though I do have it all backed up.

I'd appreciate any ideas on where to look for the cause of the problem.

Comment: Are you really sure that providing a `Wide_String` does not solve the problem? Does the compiler output remain exactly the same? You might also try using `'Wide_Image` instead of `'Image` (and then omit `To_Wide_String`).

Comment: You may also try to fully qualify the `Put` procedure by replacing `Put` with `GWindows.Drawing.Put` to quickly check if no other `Put` methods accepting a type `Printer_Canvas_Type` are visible. From what I can see, such a `Put` procedure is not defined in `GWindows.Drawing`, so the error suggests that there are `Put` procedures other than those defined in `GWindows.Drawing` visible.

Comment: Integer'Wide_Image (x) works, thank you. I will check your other suggestions tomorrow and confirm whether or not there is a difference in compiler output when I use To_Wide_String (Integer'Image (x)).

The only remaining compiler errors all relate to lines such as:

      Put (MapCanvas, 10,    3, To_String(SelectionHeaders(1)));

Again, I will look at this tomorrow - I have somewhere to go with those errors too now.

Answer (score 4):

GWindows has two string modes matching Windows API: ANSI (8-bit character) and Unicode.
The type GString is either a String or a Wide_String.
You can switch the framework's mode with ansi.cmd and unicode.cmd .
Obviously your old project was in ANSI mode.

Comment: Thank you, that seems a likely source of the problem. Given that Ada is a hobby for me (long history of other languages on non PC platforms) could you tell me how to switch to the correct framework mode? I'm not familiar with ansi.cmd and unicode.cmd

Comment: These are CMD (a built-in Windows command-line interpreter) scripts, you can find them in the `gwindows` directory. Just double-click on ansi.cmd (or run `ansi` from the CMD or Powershell).